# Woocommerce Settings API "Save Changes" button behavior?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a options page for my shipping method using the  Woocommerce Settings API.

In the options page, i added a table where the user will put some values to be used later for shipping calculation.

Now, i need to save those values when the user clicks the generated button "Save Changes", is there a hook that i can call for when that happens? I have been following [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/settings-api/) as reference to using the Woocommerce Settings API, but there is no reference of how the settings are being saved by Wordpress/Woocommerce and how to add behavior for when you need to save the options for custom fields like a table.

Even if i don't save the changes with the "Save Changes" button, how can i access the table content (Lets say JQuery) and push it to Woocommerce/php so i can store it on a database?